# How to Map reskit with json

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rest, restkit

This is the type of `JSON` I am receiving, and I need to map with my model using `restkit`. What could be a possible solution? I have no idea about `restkit`.

```
{
    -cal
        {
           -site{
                    id:""
                    name:""
                }
            -region{
                       id:""
                       name:""
                   }
            -stats[
                    {
                      key:""
                      status:""
                      -product{
                                    id:""
                                   name:""
                               }
                    },{},{}
                  ]
          }
}
```

Comment: You need to at least try following the RestKit documentation on the main page: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Comment: More precisely [refer this Document](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)